# Supervisord haproxy reload not working

Tags: bash, docker, haproxy, supervisord

I am deploying my application in a Docker container with processes managed by Supervisor. I have a Haproxy running in the container that is being reloaded (via sudo haproxy reload) when there's a change in the list of servers in my Zookeeper. The problem is that Supervisor restarts the process with an old config right away, thus not taking changes into effect.

1) I have tried supervisorctl reread, but I am trying to reload (rather than have to restart) to avoid downtime.

2) I have also considered implementing a restart of Haproxy with packet redirection, but there are currently limitations in Iptables usage in Docker (as per https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4424# and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4556)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved by the following command sequence:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3213 --syn -j DROP
sleep 1
supervisorctl -u login -p pass restart haproxy:*
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3213 --syn -j DROP
```

1.We temporarilty drop syn so that the client re-sends it until it reaches the new process.

http://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg06885.html

(Docker now supports internal iptables)

2.We gracefully restart the process group via supervisorctl